# API availability to track other objects apart from human gesture for Windows Kinect

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, kinect

APIs shipped with MS Windows Kinect SDK is all about program around Voice, Movement and Gesture Recognition related to humans.

Is there any open source or commercial APIs for tracking & recognizing dynamically moving objects like vehicles for its classification.

1. Is it feasible and good approach of employee Kinect for Automated vehicle classification than traditional image processing approaches
2. Even image processing technologies have made remarkable innovations, why fully automated vehicle classification is not  used at Most of the toll collection.
3. why existing technologies (except RFID approach) failing to classify the vehicle (i.e, they are not yet 100% accurate in classifying) or is there any other reasons apart from image processing.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a regular image processing suite to track objects that are not supported by the Kinect API.  A few being:

- [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/)
- [Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) (OpenCV in .NET)
- [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)

There is no library that directly supports the depth capabilities of the Kinect, to my knowledge.  As a result, using the Kinect over a regular camera would be of no benefit.

Comment: I agree with openCV and Emgu CV but I can't see how ImageMagic is releats to my question, as i know Photoshop is more powerful tool than ImageMagic. And Plz suggest me is it okay to use kinect rather traditional RGB camera for the application mentioned in my question.

Comment: ImageMagick has a command line interface that can be used.  I'm not suggesting that it is exactly the right tool, but it is a potential tool that could used depending on your implementation.  You can absolutely use a Kinect to accomplish what you want, but it will not provide you any advantage over a regular RGB camera.